# Linux mount partition on encrypted drive (not encrypted partition!)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, luks

Instead of encrypting a partition I encrypted an entire drive (cryptsetup -luksFormat...). Don't ask why. I created a partition and a filesystem on that partition. Let's call the encrypted virtual block device datacrypt. When I created the filesystem I also got a datacrypt1 which denoted the partition. I copied a lot of data onto it and it ran perfectly fine.

However after reboot the datacrypt1 doesn't appear! After unlocking the disk I can use parted on the virtual block device, the partition is there, everything looks fine. parted -l does find it and so does fdisk -l (reporting it as /dev/mapper/datacrypt-part1). But no /dev/mappar/datacrypt-part1 appears in the filesystem and I cannot mount it.

How can I mount the partition on virtual block device? Please help!

Comment: parttab did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to declare it in /etc/crypttab so that it get mapped.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html